# What is this Javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Below is an react HOC but I don't understand why such a syntax could work - note that two fat arrows as in *Component => props =>*?

```
const withLogging = Component => props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/logger?location=${ window.location}`);
  }, []);
  return <Component {...props } />;
};
```

And when I tried to convert it to typescript, it gives me errors

```
const withLogging = (Component: React.Component) =>(props: any)  => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/logger?location=${ window.location}`);
  }, []);
  return < Component {...props } />;
};
```

Comment: You have to add these error messages to your question or we are not able to understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I don't understand why there are two fat arrows`

This isn't some special syntax, that's just a arrow function returning another arrow function

```
// a function taking in a i returning that i
i => i

// a function taking in a i, returning another function which takes in a j and returns i + j
i => j => i + j
```

above is similar to

```
function(i) { return i; }

function(i) {
    return function(j) {
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question while I was trying to convert it to typescript to understand further